# Why is postfix not receiving mail in /var/spool/mail?

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, postfix

I am on CentOS/EL7 AWS Lightsail host trying to configure postfix to deliver incoming mail to user accounts.  However, I am not yet to the point where I see the mail arriving in /var/spool/mail/*.

A tcpdump on port 25 shows that the mail *is* reaching the server from where I am sending from (Gmail).  Also, I am sure postfix is running and that it is the active MTA listening on port 25.

Testing by sending mail from Gmail, I receive bounces with this message:

```
 The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720 [[domain omitted] [ip omitted]: generic::failed_precondition: connect error (111): Connection refused]
```

Nothing is seen regarding this traffic in /var/log/maillog.

So, perhaps the mail traffic is reaching the host (evidenced by tcpdump) but getting rejected by postfix's config or something?

Comment: What is in the maillog? What did you see in tcpdump?

Comment: tcpdump showed some minimal connection output and there was nothing in maillog.  We figured it out, solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by installing iptables on the AWS host and adding a rule to allow traffic from port 25 to the private AWS IP address.

The public IP address was seeing the mail come in (hence the minimal tcpdump output) but was unable to hand it off to the private network interface (the only one that showed in ifconfig).

Mail flowed as soon as we started the iptables service with this rule in its config.